# CGImage from Swift to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, cgimage, cgimageref

I got following troubling problem: I want to transfer a CGImage from Swift into Objective C. It just doesn't work

That's the call

```
func transferImage(cgImage: CGImage) {
objcobject.cgimage = cgImage
}
```

That's the objc header:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGImageRef *cgimage;
```

This gives my the build time error:
"Cannot assign value of type 'CGImage' to type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?>?'"

Does anybody know how to get a CGImage safely and properly from swift into objective c? CGImage doesn't work, CGImageRef doesn't work. I'm pretty desperate!

Comment: This is a very unusual ObjC interface. It is strange, and likely a mistake, to have a pointer to a ...Ref type (Ref types are already references). The fact that it's marked `assign` is also somewhat concerning (though it may be correct). Where did this ObjC code come from? Are you certain that the ObjC is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer <3, just didn't fully understand the concept of CGImageRef :/